# how to fix eclipse IDE in values string.xml problem

Tags: android

In the image below is the error in my **string.xml**:

[image]

Comment: @Misikir Hailu you should add translation of all these string tags in all your strings xml. you can check my answer for better infos.

Answer (score 0):

You should have for example hello_world string tag in all strings.xml from different languages in your project.

For example:

**el/strings.xml**

```
<string name="hello">Γειά σου</string>
```

**strings.xml (en/string.xml)**

```
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
```